# setInterval with $.post function catch errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I have setInterval function like that;

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            try{
                loader();
            }catch (e) {
                location.reload();
            }

        }, 1000);
    });

    function loader() {
        $.post("dbprocess.php", {
            process:"loadData"
        }, function (responsedData) {
            responsedData = JSON.parse(responsedData);
            $('#kitchenWrapper').html(responsedData.list);
        })
    }
```

I want to catch if loader function have a error (like 500 internal or different errors) i want reload the page. This code didn't catch runtime errors.

Comment: you can use `.fail` as explained in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) (in the section "the jqXHR object")

Comment: Thank you @RobinZigmond i think this will solve my problem.

Comment: You know that you can just fix the errors on your server instead of this "workaround"

Comment: @AlonEitan while it's true that a 500 error indicating faulty code should be fixed, it's still foolish imo to send a network request and not have some way of coping with failure, there are lots of ways beyond your control that things could go wrong.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Right, but not if the request is expected to run every 1 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did not catch any error and probably will not catch any success information as well because your `loader()` function is not returning the return of your `$.post()` function call.

your loader function should return the $.post function call return value as below:

```js
function loader() {
        return $.post("dbprocess.php", {
            process:"loadData"
        }, function (responsedData) {
            responsedData = JSON.parse(responsedData);
            $('#kitchenWrapper').html(responsedData.list);
        });
    }
```

and in your interval function you can do something like below to handle the fail returns of your `$.post()` function call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            loader().fail(function () {
                location.reload();
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
```

you can read more about the $.post fail function [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).